# Can't login on a form with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, request

I think what i do all correctly but the script do not login on a simple form.

After login i use the get method to try if i can see the user panel but i allways recive the index of the page as if it no were logged

The user and password inputs are well.

some idea ??

```
 import requests

 url = 'http://streamcloud.eu/login.html'
 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

 payload = {
    'login':'my_login',
    'password':'my_password'
 }

 r = requests.session()
 r.get(url)
 login = r.post(url,data=payload,headers=headers)
 result = r.get('http://streamcloud.eu/?op=my_account')

 print(result.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "post" your form-data to http://streamcloud.eu/. Additionally pass an additional parameter called `op` with the value `login`, to indicate, that you want to log in. All of this can be found out through a quick look at the html of the target website:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://streamcloud.eu/" class="proform" name="FL">
   <input type="hidden" name="op" value="login">
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://streamcloud.eu/">
   <input type="hidden" name="rand" value="">
   <p>
      <label>Benutzername:</label>
      <input type="text" style="font-style: normal;" name="login" value="my_login" class="text_field">
   </p>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <p>
      <label>Passwort:</label>
      <input type="password" style="font-style: normal;" name="password" class="text_field">
   </p>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <br>
   <div>
      <input type="submit" class="button blue medium" value="Senden">
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

As you can see the form posts its information to http://streamcloud.eu/:

`<form method="POST" action="http://streamcloud.eu/" class="proform" name="FL">`

Here you can see the hidden `op` parameter:

`<input type="hidden" name="op" value="login">`

Here is the updated code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://streamcloud.eu'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

payload = {
    'op': 'login',
    'login': 'my_login',
    'password': 'my_password'
}

r = requests.session()
r.get(url)
login = r.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
result = r.get('http://streamcloud.eu/?op=my_account')

print(result.text)
```

Comment: The problem was on op input. Thanks Markus!

Answer (score 0):

After r.post(...) (r.headers['Set-Cookie'])
U will obtain a cookie, so i guess u have to pass that cookie on r.get(...)